# Show Error Code:10 in login Google for cordova?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, google-signin

I'm developing a Cordova app and need to use the Google login and I have used the following Cordova plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus
now i tested on Ios its perfectly working when its come to Android it shows the 
Alert:error code 10 and stuck and funk.. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpCqI.png)

and its the following code used for google login

```
googleplusapi() {
       alert("google")
       window.plugins.googleplus.login(

       {
         'scopes': '', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
        'webClientId': '816731629411-rsv37372o75vqu6kdfmd701abmd67el2.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
         'offline': true, // optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
       },
       function (obj) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
       },
       function (msg) {
         alert('error: ' + msg);
       }


     );
```